# Most painful/slow way to kill somebody by throwing off a building?

Tags: anatomy, medicine, death, torture, injuries

Let's say that a modern dictatorship wants to publicily execute somebody by repeatedly pushing him off a building. However, as we all know from stories of people jumping off skyscrapers, death might be too quick and painless.

As such, the executioner wants to guarantee that the condemned can survive and slowly die, perhaps even allowing multiple subsequent falls.

**How can height be calculated and which vital body parts should be protected during the fall in order to prevent instant death and prolong the suffering?**

I envision something like special restraints making sure that the condemned is oriented in a certain way when hitting the ground and a protective helmet that prevents breaking the neck.

Comment: As far as I can foresee, it depends of the equipment, position as well as what you land on. Is what you want to know only about falling against an hard surface, or can it includes things like laying down shards of glass and throwing them barefooted?

Comment: In case you missed the discussion https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7933/30492 and https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7973/30492

Comment: This is not about a story. This is a fairly straightforward physics / armour~protection  / physiology~medicine question.

Comment: @elemtilas Torture questions are banned specifically.

Comment: @Trish -- No, torture queries are not "banned". They are legitimate considerations for anyone working on a fictional world or setting. Now, Some Random Person from corporate did descend from on high complaining about gruesome content; but we have not created any kind of community rule that bans gruesome content or torture related queries specifically. [Meta discussion here](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7933/why-do-we-torture-ourselves-with-this-tag) ...

Comment: and [also Meta discussion here](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7973/we-cannot-host-gruesome-depictions-of-violence-the-torture-tag-has-it-and-nee). Community consensus, while not quite rising to the level of "go take a hike", largely came down to "we'll police ourselves on matters that are germane to our topic, thank you very much".

Comment: To be frank, we're slowly moving to making "How can I cause the most pain?" questions off-topic. @elemtilas is correct that *torture* questions (and similarly, *execution* questions) are not inherently off-topic, but asking how to make them as bad as possible has captured the attention of the SE Overlords. So, I suspect if the community votes to reopen, the Mods will simply slam it shut again. Honestly, I have no problem with that. A good story doesn't need details like this and a bad one won't be saved by them.

Comment: Why not just use one of the classic slow deaths? Humans have been much too innovative with such things, and history has a lot of rather showy and painful deaths.

Comment: @JBH - Fair enough point on the overly gruesome, though this query is hardly gruesome! -- but only if the community wills & implements it, though. And it seems like this question didn't even need to be closed, because it's being steadily downvoted into oblivion. Vox populi!  However, my disagreement is not so much with that as it is with the obvious abuse of "story based" as the closure reason. If we want "overly gruesome content" as a valid closure reason, then that's fine: we need to add that to the closure reasons, and not use one of the other reasons to do it.

Comment: @elemtilas That's a reasonable point, although "not about worldbuilding within the rules..." would be just as suitable. However, I personally believe any use of a superlative (best, most, least, worst...) is grounds for "too story-based" (or opinion-based). The most/least of anything will always be based on the story. IMO, questioners should learn to avoid using superlatives and focus instead on providing the details necessary for an objective answer. After all, an adult can take more punishment than a baby, but the OP didn't even tell us that detail (I'm not a fan of assumptions).

Comment: @JBH - Fair, though "within the rules" isn't a closure reason at this moment (that I can see, and I may have missed!)  I see such verbiage as "the most" or "the biggest" more as a matter of an "imprecise and infelicitous hyperbole", not necessarily that someone is literally looking for an objective ultra plus non. This is not really a problem because it can be easily edited out, though I concur that if left unaddressed, the result would be opinion based; though not that it would be "story based", as that requires actors and plot. If the superlative were truly a matter of story based,...

Comment: ...then we could do without one or the other rationale for closure as one would be a duplicate of the other. I concur that querents should LEARN how to use this forum; and of course, I'm not saying this is a perfect question, only that the reason for closure is not valid (and the notion that the matter is somehow "against the rules" is and should be held as wrong by the community simply as a matter of we have to deal with these kinds of considerations when devising fictional worlds and settings).

Answer (score 1):

The condemned is thrown with several ropes tied to multiple cranes. The ropes are long enough that the condemned may crash into the floor but, randomly,¹ at one point during the fall, one of them may activate and make him stop falling (dislocating some member in the process), placing him back into the top of the building. This is bungee jumping... with an evil twist.

"Justifying" this process, while it rarely happens, *in theory* there is a chance for the condemned to be spared (e.g. if two cranes get triggered at the same time, the prisoner gets free).

There is also a *Circences* portion on this, in that the *happy citizens of the dictator* will be betting on how many attempts it will require, the next crane to activate, etc.

¹ Randomness is controlled by the Ministry of Truth